# Make rigid body bounce off the screen edge

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on an object that involves bubble-like movement. This object has a rigidbody and a sphere collider.

I use the `AddForce` method every 1-3 seconds to make it move continuously and slowly.

Now I'd like to know how to make the rigidbody move in the opposite direction (a.k.a bounce off) when they reach the screen edge already. I have already computed the screen edges using `ViewportToWorldPoint` method.

One ineffective solution that I thought of is to put empty game objects with collider at the edges but that won't work in my case since I'm building for mobile devices which have different screen resolutions/sizes.

Anyone know a good solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get a reflection effect, you need `Material`. Attach a bouncy material to the edges(gameObject) and let the physics calculate what should be the reaction of collision.

Create a Physics 2D material and set the bounceness to some appropriate value say `0.2`.

Regarding your issue:

> One ineffective solution that I thought of is to put empty game
>   objects with collider at the edges but that won't work in my case
>   since I'm building for mobile devices which have different screen
>   resolutions/sizes.

If you are working with UI component then dealing with boundaries should not be a problem (since it anchors with different resolution) but if it is not the case you can create a script `CameraResizer` and an enum `Anchor` (Left, Right, Top, Bottom) and using the same way `ViewportToWorldPoint` you can align your empty gameObject (boundary) to any screen size by attaching it the gameObject.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When you said `Attach a bouncy material to the edges of the ViewPort`, is there a ViewPort object that is accessible in the Unity editor? Still new and figuring my way with Unity sorry :P It would be helpful if there is, so that I won't have to manually worry about the size of my collision boxes for different screen sizes

Comment: There is no ViewPort object. I mean attach material to the gameObject used as a boundary and these boundaries are supposed to be aligned to the corners of the screen using `ViewportToWorldPoint`.

Comment: Ah I see. For a second there, I thought there was. I get it now. I will try to get the bounce working with the method you suggested. I'll update when I finish.

Comment: Got the bounce effect I was looking. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure i got the idea. But i think i had the same problem when i was writing an old mobile game.

I had the same idea you did, use empty game objects with box collider on the edges, but then i thought, this isn't responsive, so i wrote this code:

```
public class Walls_c : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform righttop;
    public Transform rightbottom;
    public Transform lefttop;
    public Transform leftbottom;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        righttop.transform.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1,1,0));
        rightbottom.transform.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1,0,0));
        lefttop.transform.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0,1,0));
        leftbottom.transform.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0,0,0));   
    }
}
```

With this, i always get the corners of the screen. It's no fancy... but it works.

Let me now if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This helped in determining the edges of the screen so that I can properly position my empty game objects regardless of screen size.